# How can I get bootstrap 3 looks in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a template in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_store&stacked=h) that uses bootstrap 3.

[image]
Code of above

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
      .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
       .jumbotron {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

      /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
      footer {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 25px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Online Store</h1>      
      <p>Mission, Vission & Values</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Your Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br><br>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Online Store Copyright</p>  
    <form class="form-inline">Get deals:
      <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I change the bootstrap it looks bad as follows

[image]

Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
      .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
       .jumbotron {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

      /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
      footer {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 25px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Online Store</h1>      
      <p>Mission, Vission & Values</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Your Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br><br>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Online Store Copyright</p>  
    <form class="form-inline">Get deals:
      <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Ok. As the version is changed so looks may different. I also made the navbar not similar in this in another way in bootstrap 4. But I want to get the image gallery same look. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is in many ways a fundamentally different framework from Bootstrap 3.  They've changed their approach to Mobile First, and have fully embraced the Flex model over other layouts.  Numerous components from Bootstrap 3 have also been reworked or fully removed, so it's important that you're reading the Migration documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/

For example, in 3.x you achieved part of your layout through the `panel` component.  This component has been fully replaced with `card` in 4.x so your code would need to reflect this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header bg-success text-light">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
  <div class="card-body"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-fluid" alt="Image"></div>
  <div class="card-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
</div>
```

**Note**: Bootstrap 4s background color utility classes are significantly different from the less-saturated options from 3.x so you might need to make some customizations to achieve an exact change.

Similarly with the Nav component there are fundamental changes; `.navbar-inverse` no longer exists.  Instead you would apply your color scheme through a different set of classes:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

You can read more about the new navigational menu and its color scheme options here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Comment: I like your answer. It is better if someone can test your answer whether it fulfill the requirement or not. For testing you can edit my MWE and add in your answer.

Comment: That sounds remarkably like you just want someone to write the code for you. Your problem isn’t an issue of code having an error or an unexpected result; you simply haven’t attempted to update your BS3 formatting to BS4.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent opportunity for you to apply what you have learned from the above answer and apply it to your own project. No better way to learn than by doing!